# Client side Application without any Framework

Tags: jquery, client, client-side

We are working on one web application. The server side we are using Ruby on Rails for Web APIs.

In the client side we are planning to use JQuery with Ajax. Can you please suggest that the better approach? If i go with this without using any client side frameworks (AngualrJs, ReactJS etc) what are the disadvantages? So is it necessary to go with any framework?

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the project. Frameworks like Angular are bunch of JS code, so whatever they have can be coded. Without knowing the details of the project all I can say is something general like: if you are going to use the aspects of such frameworks, recoding everything will be really time consuming this is 1. 2) Those frameworks are coded by great engineers and has been revisited again and again, so those algorithms in them have great time and space complexities, if you try to imitate something in that framework, it is possible that you end up making things slower. And last but not least, especially Angular is google's piece of work so it is designed to work perfectly with Chrome etc. Nevertheless, I can not see a reason not to use them if necessary, angular etc are pretty popular frameworks and mostly cached in many user's browsers, so it wont even take time to download them.